# Prove $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, x_{n+1}=f(x_n) $ with $|f'(x)|< \theta < 1$ converges for $n \rightarrow \infty$ and it has a fixed point.

Tags: fixed-point-theorems

Show that

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$x_{n+1} :=f(x_n)$ with arbitrary $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$

with $|f'(x)|< \theta < 1$

converges such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=x^*$ and $f(x^*)=x^*$.

So far I have shown that $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous and that it follows that

$|x_n-x_{n-1}|\leq \theta^{n-1} |x_1-x_0|$, which for $n \to \infty$ approaches $0$.

How can I show that $x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, i.e:

$\forall \varepsilon>0 \quad \exists N\in\mathbb{N} \quad \forall m,n \ge N \colon \quad \left|x_m-x_n \right|<\varepsilon $

I know that fixed point theorems use what I found out, however I am afraid I cannot use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$|x_n - x_m| \le |x_n - x_{n+1}| + |x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}| + \ldots + |x_{m-1} - x_m| \le (\theta^n + \theta^{n+1} + \ldots + \theta^{m-1})|x_1 - x_0| < (\theta^n + \theta^{n+1} + \ldots)|x_1 - x_0| = \frac{\theta^n}{1-\theta}|x_1-x_0|$

The first inequality is triangle inequality, the second is by what you showed, the third is because we added more positive terms, and the fourth is by convergence of geometric series with ratio less than $1$. Now, you see that it's Cauchy, so can you take it from here?

Comment: I do not understand the third inequality, what did happen there?

Comment: $\theta > 0$, so any power of it is also positive. We took our original expression $\sum_{i=n}^{m-1} \theta^i$ and added even more positive terms, so it increases.

Comment: You summed it to infinity. I understand. Many thanks Sir!